# Unit Test auto-wiried Caliburn Micro Views

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am working on a large project (10+ Developers) using Caliburn Micro and we want to have 90+% code coverage on unit tests, including the UI layer. Specifically we want to be able to test if the Caliburn Micro auto wiring between the ViewModel and View is correct (wasn't broken things such as by a variable name change). I have seen that the Full Caliburn has a Testing Namespace but there does not seem to be any such functionality in Micro. 
All I want is a way to test if the binding has been done correctly for the View-ViewModel connections or to have the test fail is some connection has been broken. If that is not possible I would like suggestions of other ways to do a similar sort of automated testing.
Thank you all for your time and help.